# Setting the cell or text alignment of a document.table instance

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I am producing a flow document that has a document.table instance added to it as a block.
I produced my table using this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-build-a-table-programmatically)

I'm trying to set the second group row of the table so that the text aligns at the right side of the cells whilst keeping the other group rows at centred.

I can set the whole table alignment using `table1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;` but i want to be able to set just a group rows, rows, or individual cells to have the right text align.

This is my code

```
            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();

            doc.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            doc.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Century Gothic");



            Table table1 = new Table();

            table1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            doc.Blocks.Add(table1);
            int numberOfColumns = 12;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
            {
                table1.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
            }

            table1.Columns[0].Width = new GridLength(125);
            //Header row group
            table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            TableRow currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new 
            Run("Header 1"))));
            currentRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = numberOfColumns;

            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[1];
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new 
            Run("Header 2"))));
            currentRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = numberOfColumns;

            //Main body
            table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                table1.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
                currentRow = table1.RowGroups[1].Rows[i];


                currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(Time))));
                //Rest of the columns here (These columns need right text alignment)
             }
```

[I have found this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.tablecell.textalignment?view=netframework-4.8) but when i try and do this `currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(Time)).TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right));`
 I get this error

> cannot convert from 'System.Windows.TextAlignment' to 'System.Windows.Documents.Block'

Does anybody have a solution or alternative?

Comment: Strange. When I do it in XAML, it works: `<TableCell TextAlignment="Right"><Paragraph><Run Text="xyz"/></Paragraph></TableCell>`